# import { PluginConfig, ProtractorPlugin } from './plugins';

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am getting this issue when running the spec file.

before updating my dependencies it is working fine.
 I was trying the update dependencies in the package.json 
so I enter the this command in the terminal npm update --save.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because there is a problem with your typescript compiler. You need to add @types/node and other typescript dependencies to fix this error. If you run your tests in javascript this problem should not arise. So please check your tsconfig and see if your are using ES6 libraries. Also check if the types for selenium, node, jasmine and jasminewd2 are added in your package.json.